# How to Create Report that Get Image from Online CRM database using FetchXml Query?

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, ssrs-2012, fetchxml

I have a requirement to display corresponding property images which awx_propertyid is equal to the image entity awx_propertyid report in fetchXML SSRS report. 
Now I would like to display the images of each property which is stored in online CRM as note entity, I also added fetchXML query which results in the documentbody column from Notes of that property. for that purpose In report design view, on the Insert tab, click Image. On the General tab of the Image Properties dialog box, Select the image source and select Database.
Use this field the expression is as follows:`Convert.FromBase64String( MID(Convert.ToBase64String (Fields!annotation_documentbody.Value),105))`
**Mime type** : `image/jpeg` 
But when the report is running it displays a red cross sign. whats going wrong please anyone tells me???

```
 <fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="true">
      <entity name="awx_image">
    <attribute name="awx_imageid" />
         <attribute name="awx_mimetype" alias="Awx_MimeType"/>
         <attribute name="awx_propertyid" />
    <attribute name="awx_filename"/>
       <filter type="and">
              <condition attribute="awx_primary" operator="eq" value="1" />
     <condition attribute="awx_mimetype" operator="not-null" />
    <condition attribute="awx_filename" operator="eq" value="Hamm.jpg" />
            </filter>
    <link-entity name="awx_property" from="awx_propertyid" to="awx_propertyid" link-type="inner" alias="property">
    <attribute name="awx_address" />
          <filter type="and">
            <condition attribute="awx_countryid" operator="eq" uiname="New Zealand" uitype="awx_country" value="{E65C8093-A299-DD11-BE91-0050569C0CB2}" />
          </filter>
          <link-entity name="awx_availability" from="awx_propertyid" to="awx_propertyid" link-type="inner" alias="al">
            <filter type="and">
              <condition attribute="statecode" operator="eq" value="0" />
            </filter>
          </link-entity>
        </link-entity>
         <link-entity name="annotation" from="objectid" to="awx_imageid" link-type="inner" alias="annotation">
          <attribute name="documentbody" />
     <attribute name="mimetype" alias="anotationmime"/>
            <filter type="and">
              <condition attribute="documentbody" operator="not-null" />
            </filter>
          </link-entity>
      </entity>
    </fetch>
```

Comment: Did you find answer to your question ?

Comment: @BipinBhandari Not right now But when I have deployed report in Client On-Premise CRM environment, report displayed images nicely. I think in Client Online CRM there might be some security reason that's why report is not showing any images because I have also retrieved images successfully in a Online CRM trial account. Still I am working on this issue.